# Designing a weekly calendar with react on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, coffeescript

I am trying to design an appointment schedule layed out by week in my react on rails application. It should look like this when done:

[image]

- Colored boxes will be bootstrap classes depending on the status of the appointment. They should be links to the individual appointment show pages (I know I don't have this done yet, it's not my primary concern at the moment).

Here is the data structure I'm working with in JSON:

```
{
  "clients": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Oscar",
      "appointments": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "status": "Not Done",
          "report": "Not Started",
          "start": "2017-09-24T12:06:19.000Z",
          "finish": "2017-09-24T12:36:19.000Z",
          "scheduled": "2017-09-24T12:09:19.000Z",
          "duration": null
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "status": "Not Done",
          "report": "Not Started",
          "start": "2017-09-18T13:07:56.000Z",
          "finish": "2017-09-18T13:37:56.000Z",
          "scheduled": "2017-09-18T13:10:56.000Z",
          "duration": null
        }
      ],
      "url": "http:\/\/localhost:3000\/clients\/2.json"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Molly",
      "appointments": [
        {
          "id": 4,
          "status": "Not Done",
          "report": "Not Started",
          "start": "2017-09-21T11:09:31.000Z",
          "finish": "2017-09-21T11:39:31.000Z",
          "scheduled": "2017-09-21T11:12:31.000Z",
          "duration": null
        }
      ],
      "url": "http:\/\/localhost:3000\/clients\/3.json"
    }]}
```

Appointments.js.coffee

```
@Appointments = React.createClass

getInitialState: ->
    clients: @props.clients

  getDefaultProps: ->
    clients: []

  render: ->
    React.DOM.div
      className: 'client-appts'
      React.DOM.h2
        className: 'title'
        'Clients Title'
      React.DOM.table
          className: 'table table-bordered'
          React.DOM.thead null,
            React.DOM.tr null,
              React.DOM.th null, 'Client'
              React.DOM.th null, 'col 2'
              React.DOM.th null, 'col 3'
          React.DOM.tbody null,
            for client in @state.Clients
              React.createElement Client, key: client.id, client: client
```

This is my client.js.coffee

```
@Client= React.createClass
  render: ->
      React.DOM.tr null,
        React.DOM.td null, @props.client.name
        for appointment in @props.client.appointments
          React.createElement Appointment, key: appointment.id, appointment: appointment
```

This is my appointment.js.coffee

```
@Appointment = React.createClass
    render: ->
      React.DOM.td null,
        React.DOM.p null, @props.appointment.status
        React.DOM.p null, @props.appointment.report
```

I know rails OK, but am new to react. How do I design the structure so that the appointments show up only when they're supposed to. Once I have that figured out I need to figure out how to click through pages for different weeks. How do I design the react components? Anyone see another good example on S/O or G/H?

Comment: just as a side note, coffeescript 2 was recently released and can output JSX, so if you haven't done too much coding yet it might be worth checking that out.

Comment: Thanks. Going to look into it. Hopefully the built in gem has an updated version.